# List Members of an Index in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, database-metadata

I've search here in StackOverflow and other sites, but I'm still not able to list the members of an index. The simplified case is:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  salary INT NOT NULL,
  bonus INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_employee_1 ON employee (name);

CREATE INDEX idx_employee_2 ON employee ((salary + bonus) desc, name);
```

How can I get the list of indexes with their members as shown below?

```
table_name  index_name      is_unique  ordinal  member          is_ascending
----------  --------------  ---------  -------  --------------  ------------
employee    idx_employee_1  true             1  name            true
employee    idx_employee_2  false            1  salary + bonus  false
employee    idx_employee_2  false            2  name            true
```

Comment: There are several functions to get details from the indexes, check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG

Comment: That is rather difficult. All the information is in `pg_index`, but the index expressions are in parsed form in `indexprs`. You can deparse them with `pg_get_expr()`, but you'll have to parse the result again (there can be more than one index expression...). Perhaps you can use `pg_get_indexdef()` and parse that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pg_indexes` (simpler) or `pg_index` (more informative).

```sql
select *
from pg_indexes
where tablename = 'employee'
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/tkTzoTVF)

Read about [pg_indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/view-pg-indexes.html) and [pg_index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/catalog-pg-index.html) in the docs.